# Error: Cant set property value to null in a boolean property in bean

Tags: jquery, jsf, datatable, radio-button

I have a boolean(primitive) variable in my bean. I need its value to be true or false depending on the radio button selected by user.

I am implementing JSF radio buttons in two different columns of the same row of a jsf datatable.
It is a requirement that i use radio buttons in two columns of the same row.

Now, i have to make sure just one of the buttons id selected for a row.

So my approach is ,

i am using one radio button mapped to the bean and the other radio button as a dummy.

```
<h:column>
 <h:selectOneRadio id="mixtas" value="#{bean.mixtas}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="true"></f:selectItem>
 </h:selectOneRadio>    
</h:column>

<h:column>
 <h:selectOneRadio id="exclusi" >
  <f:selectItem itemValue="true"></f:selectItem>
 </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:column>
```

And i am handling the select just one functionality using jquery

```
$('input[id*="mixtas"]').live("click",function(){
    var $index = this.id.split(':')[2]; \\to identify the row index
    var $id = $index+":exclusi:0"; \\generating id for other radio button
    $('table[id$="'+$id+'"]').attr("checked",false); \\ to make the other radio false   
});

$('input[id*="exclusi"]').live("click",function(){
    var $index = this.id.split(':')[2]; \\ to identify the row index
    var $id = $index+":mixtas:0"; \\generating id for other radio button
    $('input[id$="'+$id+'"]').attr("checked",false); \\ to make the other radio false   
});
```

The functionality works . Atleast half of it (i am still working on the rest).

But the issue is .

If i the mixtas radio button is unchecked and i try to proceed to another page.
It gives error "**Property mixtas cannot be set to null**".

Is there any way to assign it a value false rather than null. Maybe in jquery or through bean.

Any suggestions please ....

Thanks In advance.

Comment: is this error being raised for a specific line , is it an error from firebug or server side?

Comment: This is serverError. It fails to set value null to the primitive boolean type on page submission.

Comment: you can always turn boolean into object Boolean....

Comment: Hi everyone . Sorry to say but the functionality just got updated. Now i have two variables. Both can be null. But if one is true other will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your previous questions I assume that you are using JSF 2.0. Then you could get the desired behavior without custom javascript:

```
<h:column>
  <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.mixtas}" id="mixtas">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="true"/>
    <f:ajax render="exclusi"/>
  </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:column>

<h:column>
  <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.mixtas}" id="exclusi">
     <f:selectItem itemValue="false"/>
     <f:ajax render="mixtas"/>
  </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:column>
```

Comment: Hi. The functionality worked but its still giving the same error. Cant set value to null. Any ideas.

Comment: Also there is a slight update in requirement. now i have two variables. Its not necessary to select any. But if one is selected, other will be false.

Comment: @Karanveer Maybe you still have your javascript interfering. Otherwise I don't see where the value should be null. You could use a Boolean object instead of a primitive type. This can be null.

Comment: @Karanveer Btw: I see in your question history that you did not accept any of your questions. Please read this: [How accepting answers works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/161675)

Comment: You could use  `Boolean` instead of `boolean` primitive. The object can be null.